# how to set binding for the label in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I need to bind a property to a label. i have written the following code:
 xaml for the label is

```
<Label Canvas.Left="807.3" Canvas.Top="148.9" Height="33.567" x:Name="label2"
       Width="98" FontFamily="Tw Cen MT" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"
       Foreground="#FFFEE3A4"
       Content="{Binding Path=UserInformation.AccountBalance,Mode=OneWay}">
    <Label.Background>
        <ImageBrush />
    </Label.Background>
</Label>
```

The class whcih have the AccountBalance

```
public class CustomerInformation : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CustomerInformation()
        {
            _Balance = 0.0;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion

 public double AccountBalance
        {
            get { return _Balance; } 
        set 
        {
            _wepaBalance = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("AccountBalance");
        } 

        }

 protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

datacontext is set as below

this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;

behind the xaml.cs the following code is written to access the UserInfo which is a global object

```
public CustomerInformation UserInformation
        {
            get
            {

                return Globalobjs._Object.UserInfo;
            }
        }
```

xamls.cs is derived from Window only.

The problem is PropertyChangedEventHandler of INotifyPropertyChanged is always null when called .

Can any 1 please help me on this issue?

Comment: can you post the src code as well?

Comment: Where are you setting you `DataContext`? Could you please also add code for the `NotifyChanged` implementation?

Comment: Sure VoodooChild and townsean. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
```

This is the `Window`, yet you are setting the `Window` instance as the `DataContext`. Set the `DataContext` to the `UserInformation`.

```
this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = Globalobjs._Object.UserInfo;
```

Comment: I have got other controls which bind to different properties of the Window.

Comment: @logeeks Setting the LayoutRoot.DataContext with the parent of the LayoutRoot makes no sense; you do realize this don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Does the datacontext that you are binding to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

If this is not an MVVM patterned project, ensure that the class that contains the property that you are binding to implements that interface, and be sure to call the delegate for the event when you change the property (e.g. OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty"))

If it is an MVVM project and you are not using a framework, it is best to derive all of your ViewModels from a ViewModel base that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks.AccountBalance is a member of a global object which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. I am updating the post with the code of the class which contain AccountBalance.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the Windows's DataContext.  But the Windows DataContext is not the same as the Windows's code behind, where you have UserInformation property defined.  To access a property defined in your Window's code behind, you have to set your Window's Name property,  then use the following binding instead:

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=YourWindowName, Path=UserInformation.AccountBalance,Mode=OneWay}"
```